# Squashing history commits in a pushed branch

Tags: git, squash, git-squash

### Background

I have a [GitHub project](https://github.com/KamilPacanek/reactor-knockoff-enhanced) I'm currently working on and at the same time I'm learning Git. Today I've read about squashing with `rebase` command and wanted to try it on some commits that I've pushed a few days ago.

The commits I want to work with are `2b16710` and `32fef8e`. On my local repository master branch log looks like this:

```
* f49573f - (21 hours ago) [#12] Add durability icons - KamilPacanek (origin/enh/12-durability, enh/12-durability)
* 1c9fec4 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Move reactor parts handling to ReactorPanel - KamilPacanek
*   d68bebe - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/7-introducing-clock-ticks' - KamilPacanek (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
|\
| * 2b16710 - (2 days ago) [#7] Refactors - KamilPacanek
| * 32fef8e - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek
|/
*   f699930 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/28-oper-icons-rework' - KamilPacanek
|\
| * ffb3672 - (2 days ago) [#28] Reactor icon animates when reactor is working - KamilPacanek
```

As you can see, after the commits I've made a feature branch (`enh/12-durability`).

### What I was trying to do

I've tried the following approach - `checkout` the master, did an experimental branch and executed following commands to squash the commits.

`git rebase -i f699930`

I've marked the `2b16710` with `fixup` and it resulted in the following tree:

```
* a7641cc - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek (HEAD -> exp-squash)
| * f49573f - (21 hours ago) [#12] Add durability icons - KamilPacanek (origin/enh/12-durability, enh/12-durability)
| * 1c9fec4 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Move reactor parts handling to ReactorPanel - KamilPacanek
| *   d68bebe - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/7-introducing-clock-ticks' - KamilPacanek (origin/master, master)
| |\
|/ /
| * 2b16710 - (2 days ago) [#7] Refactors - KamilPacanek
| * 32fef8e - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek
|/
*   f699930 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/28-oper-icons-rework' - KamilPacanek
|\
| * ffb3672 - (2 days ago) [#28] Reactor icon animates when reactor is working - KamilPacanek
```

After that, I've made some diffs to ensure that `a7641cc` contains the same changes as these two squashed ones and it did.

Next, I've tried to figure out how to merge these changes to my `master` and finally push to `origin` to rewrite the history, BUT:

1. I'm worried about the `enh/12-durability` branch - I'm the only contributor so I have full control over the process but first I must know how to apply new history to the branch (or maybe I didn't have to as I'm going to merge it with master after work is done)
2. I don't know why it keeps showing me the tree in such way - I thought the squashing rewrites the commits so instead of two I will have one. So I think I need an explanation whether my understanding is wrong or it will look like that after some force push.

**I wanted to achieve** something like this (notice there is no `2b16710` commit):

```
* f49573f - (21 hours ago) [#12] Add durability icons - KamilPacanek (origin/enh/12-durability, enh/12-durability)
* 1c9fec4 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Move reactor parts handling to ReactorPanel - KamilPacanek
*   d68bebe - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/7-introducing-clock-ticks' - KamilPacanek (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
|\
| * 32fef8e - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek
|/
*   f699930 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/28-oper-icons-rework' - KamilPacanek
|\
| * ffb3672 - (2 days ago) [#28] Reactor icon animates when reactor is working - KamilPacanek
```

Am I on the right track? I have feeling that I need to cherrypick some of the commits to make it right.. but I don't know.

Comment: Rebase does not modify anything to your existing commits, it only creates new ones. Did you expect it to also delete the commits it rebases? It clearly should *not*. Also, in your expected result at the end, your last commits appear with the same hash, which is impossible with different ancestors.

Comment: Yeah, I really thought that I can "hide" some unnecessarily pushed commit. Like here, if that would be before the push I would have squash these commits locally. So maybe that's what it should be done with the `rebase` tool. To modify the unpushed tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an experimental branch `exp-squash` and worked on it. So far, only `exp-squash`'s history has been rewritten. `master` and `enh/12-durability` are unchanged.

If you run `git rebase -i f699930` on `master`, the graph will look almost the same, except that `HEAD->master` will decorate the newly generated commit, supposing `abc1234`, like this:

```
* abc1234 - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek (HEAD -> master)
| * f49573f - (21 hours ago) [#12] Add durability icons - KamilPacanek (origin/enh/12-durability, enh/12-durability)
| * 1c9fec4 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Move reactor parts handling to ReactorPanel - KamilPacanek
| *   d68bebe - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/7-introducing-clock-ticks' - KamilPacanek (origin/master)
| |\
|/ /
| * 2b16710 - (2 days ago) [#7] Refactors - KamilPacanek
| * 32fef8e - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek
|/
*   f699930 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/28-oper-icons-rework' - KamilPacanek
|\
| * ffb3672 - (2 days ago) [#28] Reactor icon animates when reactor is working - KamilPacanek
```

This way, the history of `master` is rewritten. Its head moves from `d68bebe` to `abc1234`. `abc1234` contains the same changes with the squashed `2b16710` and `32fef8e`. `d68bebe`, as a merge commit and without `-p`, is removed. You don't need to apply or merge `abc1234` to `master`, because it's already on `master`.

As to `enh/12-durability` or any other branches that are created from a commit newer than `d68bebe`, you can choose not to merge `abc1234` to them because they already contain the equivalent changes to those of `abc1234` in the history.

`enh/12-durability` still contains some commits that belong to the old history of `master`, `32fef8e`, `2b16710` and `d68bebe`. If you later merge `enh/12-durability` to the new `master`, these commits will be introduced to `master` again. So it's better to rewrite `enh/12-durability` too.

```
git rebase --onto abc1234 d68bebe enh/12-durability
```

The graph will be like:

```
* abc3333 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Add durability icons - KamilPacanek (HEAD->enh/12-durability)
* abc2222 - (21 hours ago) [#12] Move reactor parts handling to ReactorPanel - KamilPacanek
* abc1234 - (2 days ago) [#7] Implements game ticks - KamilPacanek (master)
*   f699930 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'enh/28-oper-icons-rework' - KamilPacanek
|\
| * ffb3672 - (2 days ago) [#28] Reactor icon animates when reactor is working - KamilPacanek
```

And then you need to force-push `master` and `enh/12-durability` to update their counterparts in the remote repository.

The last graph you want to achieve is impossible. At least you can't keep the commit hashes unchanged after you rewrite the history. Regardless of hashes, it's possible to construct such a graph, with `git rebase`, or with `git reset --hard` and `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't pay attention to the hashes as I know that they cannot be the same because they having different parents. But reading what `--onto` is doing it seems like it does exactly what I want. It detaches the branch from the old path and attaches to new. I guess I can also do something like `git rebase --onto 32fef8e d68bebe master` to **cut** the `2b16710` refactor commit and lose it.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted - the only difference is that newly created commit (`abc1234` in your example) doesn't show as merge commit but as if I've fast forward. But I get it is because we were rebasing, so I couldn't expect more. Thank you, this was very helpful!